# What's the fastest way to read/write to disk in .NET?

Tags: .net, winapi, streaming, disk

I've got a little program that reads and writes files on disk.  Breaking it down to the most simple level, it reads bytes from one file stream and writes them to another.  It performs its duties fine, but it isn't the fastest thing.

I've seen other applications that can tear through a gigabyte or more of reads/writes in amazing speeds.  Obviously they're operating closer to the metal than a little .NET app.

What are the most efficient .NET APIs for streaming to/from the disk?  What win32 APIs are available (and worth p/invoking for) for speedy disk access?

Comment: I don't see why WinAPI calls should be any faster than the .NET classes - after all, the latter use the former internally. Aside from that, would a memory-mapped file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_mapped_file) be suitable perhaps?

Comment: Why would Dot.net have more than one way to write to a file ? Reading and writing files is pretty basic and it makes no sense in having a "fast" and "slow" form - as no one would use the "slow" version given they both have the same objectives.

Comment: Within a half hour I could set up a test comparing .net file operations (naive implementations, perhaps, which is part of the question) and a native application with intensive IO (such as QuickPAR) that will blow the doors off the .NET app.  That's the point of the question--How do you achieve optimal disk throughput in .NET?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fast file I/O is less about the specific API calls you make, but rather about how you architect your application to work with I/O.

If you are performing all of your I/O operations on a single thread in a sequential manner, for example

1. Read block into memory
2. Process block in memory somehow
3. Write block out to file
4. Repeat until done...

you are bottlenecking the system's I/O bandwidth in the processing loop of a single thread. An alternative, but more complicated design is to multithread your application to maximize throughput and avoid wait time. This allows the system to take advantage of both CPU and I/O controller bandwidth simultaneously. A typical design for this would look something like:

1. One (or more) worker threads read data from disk and add them to a shared input queue
2. One (or more) worker threads read blocks from the shared input queue, process them and add them to a shared output queue
3. One (or more) worker threads read processed blocked from the shared output queue and write them to the appropriate output files.

This is not an easy architecture to design right, and requires quite a bit of thought to avoid creating in-memory lock contention, or overwhelm the system with concurrent I/O requests. You also need to provide control metadata so that the state of output processing is not managed on the call stack of a thread but rather in the input/output work queues. You also have to make sure that you transform and write the output in the correct order, since with multi-threaded I/O you can't be sure work is placed on the input queue in a guaranteed order. It's complicated - but it is possible, and it can have a dramatic difference in throughput over a serial approach.

If you really have the time and want to squeeze every ounce of performance from the system, you could also use [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198(VS.85).aspx) - a relatively low-level API - to maximize throughput.

Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

.NET file support is fast enough (comparable to native Win32 functions). Several options that can help you improve your performance:

1. If your read/write is sequential, help the caching manager by applying appropriate strategy - provide [RandomAccess or SequentalScan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions.aspx), when instantiating FileStream
2. Consider using a larger memory buffer for storing read data
3. If you copy many small files, you can first read many files into a memory buffer at once (see 2), and then write the files to disk
4. If source and destination streams are located in different places (that is, not on the same hard drive, maybe one file on the network, the other on a local hard drive, etc.), you can use the asynchronous pattern to speed-up, read data by using [BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx), then write data using [BeginWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginwrite.aspx), and while data is being written read next data block using BeginRead.
5. If you still think that performance is not enough (however from my test it is equatable or even faster than the internal Windows copy), you can use the [CopyFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363852%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 function (but this function works with files, not streams).

Comment: Part of the question is about using it properly, which this answer at least tries to accomplish.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you profiled your application to determine if the disk I/O was the bottleneck?

What type of hardware are you running this on?  What is the hardware configuration?

In .NET you may try the `System.IO.File` namespace.

For Win32 functions you may try the CreateFile, WriteFile, ReadFile series.

An example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540534(VS.85).aspx

This is definitely not cut and dried.  It's all about testing and measuring.

Comment: I'd personally be *very* surprised if the disk IO was the problem... I have never had any problems maxing out disk IO with any of the .NET primitives... (unless perhaps he is running .NET 1 where I believe the file streams did not have a built-in buffer)

Comment: The question wasn't about how, but how FAST.  Thanks for the tip on System.IO.File (sarcasm, ftw).

Answer (score 0):

`BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` with a suitable buffer size are pretty fast. If you are reading into structures, the unsafe approach described [in this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ReadingStructures.aspx) will get you reading fast, and writing is similar. I also agree with the suggestion to double-check that I/O is really the bottleneck. I first came across that article due to such a mistake.