# What is the fastest way to load text file into RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, text, load, richtextbox, performance

I load text file into RichTextBox using OpenFIleDialog. But when a large amount of text is (for example song text about 50-70 lines) and I click OPEN program hangs for a few second (~3-5). Is it normal? Maybe there is some faster way or component to load text file? If my question is an inappropriate just delete it. Thanx.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = text;
            }
        }
```

I guess maybe `ReadAllLines` impeds it?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to read the file and fill the richtextbox ?

Comment: Yes, of cource. Updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a similar question that deals with the fastest way of reading/writing files: [What's the fastest way to read/write to disk in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084927/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-write-to-disk-in-net)

However, 50-70 lines is *nothing*.. no matter how you read, it should fly in immediately. Are you maybe reading from a network share or something else that is causing the delay?

Edit:
Now that I see your code: Remove the loop and just write `richTextBox1.Text = text;` once. It doesn't make sense to assign the string in the loop since you already read the complete content of the file by using `ReadAllText`.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
    string text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    richTextBox1.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: Thanx, I don't know, maybe my Pentium IV is weak, or ReadAllLines does it slow.

Comment: Thanx a lot. I've understood that loop is an inappropriate just now! Al answers are very helpfull. Thanx.

Answer (score 6):

```
void LoadFileToRTB(string fileName, RichTextBox rtb)
{
      rtb.LoadFile(File.OpenRead(fileName), RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText); // second parameter you can change to fit for you
      // or
      rtb.LoadFile(fileName);
      // or
      rtb.LoadFile(fileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText); // second parameter you can change to fit for you
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the for loop, because is useless:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
richTextBox1.Text = text;
```

`text` is a string that already contains all the text of the file to pass to the textBox.

Doing:

```
for(int i=0, i < text.Lengt-1; i++)
    richTextBox1.Text = text;
```

you're assigning the text read from the file `text.Length-1` times (`Length` is the number of characters of the string) and that's useless.

Comment: Thanx, the is useless, looking absurdly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```