# RichTextBox performance issues(Too much text in the textbox)

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, load, richtextbox

Currently I am trying to load my log files into a RichTextBox, but the problem is that when I scroll down the text always loads because the log file has a lot of data (65mb). The performance deteriorates so much within 50 seconds that my program freezes.

Does anyone have improvement suggestions or a solution for me .
My current trainee task is to write a search tool where you can read log files and search them for certain keywords. Should I possibly use an element other than a RichTextBox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to load text file into RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323129/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-load-text-file-into-richtextbox)

Comment: The problem is not to load the stuff in but rather that the RichTextBox can't handle such a huge amount of text (420000 lines).

Comment: Try to use a `ListView` where each line is a separate entry, then you can have a `TextBox` that would filter your collection of rows. This way you have both criteria sorted.

Comment: Can I still highlight things ( texranges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

65meg of data is a lot to hold into memory, whichever way you look at this.

Meaning there could well be other issues you will encounter along the way.

Work on them when you find them though.

For now you need something that can possibly work.

This sample here uses a listbox to present a row per line.

Each row is a listview which is horizontally arranged.

The data for each listview consists of the strings split using a regex.

One with no match, up to three if one match is found in a line.

There is a viewmodel (RunHI) per chunk which has a IsMatch property.

When that is true, the background is set to yellow by a datatrigger.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-Highlight-Matching-71ad5a04

The sample works with a fixed list of strings but you can readallines https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8 into an array and foreach that.